# JAVA : Cannot copy the images from one folder to a word document located in different folder

Tags: java, selenium

I need to copy all the images located in a Folder to a word doc in a different folder(word doc is created during run time with the same name as srcfile). When i run the below code, No exceptions are seen but the images are not copied to word document. can someone please help me

Code:

```
File srcfile=new File("C:\\reports\\test"
            + fileName() + "\\images");
File destfile = new File("D:\\Evidences"+ "\\test" + fileName() + ".docx");

destfile.getParentFile().mkdir();
destfile.createNewFile();

    File[] list = srcfile.listFiles();
int img=list.length;
System.out.println(img);
for(int k=0;k<list.length;k++){
    if (list[k].isFile()){
        System.out.println("File"+list[k].getName());
        if(srcfile.isFile()){
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(srcfile);
            XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(fis);
            XWPFParagraph p = doc.createParagraph();
            XWPFRun r = p.createRun();
            r.addPicture (fis, XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, 
"C:\\reports\\test"+ fileName() + "\\images\\"+imageName() + ".png", 
Units.toEMU(200), Units.toEMU(200));
            fis.close();
            FileOutputStream fos =new FileOutputStream(destfile);
            doc.write(fos);
            fos.close();
            doc.close();

        }
    }
    else if (list[k].isDirectory()){
        System.out.println("Directory"+list[k].getName());
        if(srcfile.isFile()){
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(srcfile);
            XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(fis);
            XWPFParagraph p = doc.createParagraph();
            XWPFRun r = p.createRun();
            r.addPicture (fis, XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, 
"C:\\reports\\test"+ fileName() + "\\images\\"+imageName() + ".png", 
Units.toEMU(200), Units.toEMU(200));
            fis.close();
            FileOutputStream fos =new FileOutputStream(destfile);
            doc.write(fos);
            fos.close();
            doc.close();
    }
}
}
```

Console:

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -agentlib:jvmhook
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xrunjvmhook -Xbootclasspath/a:"C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\Unified Functional Testing\bin\java_shared\classes";"C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\Unified Functional Testing\\bin\java_shared\classes\jasmine.jar";"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin"
12
File0.PNG
File1.PNG
File10.PNG
File2.PNG
File3.PNG
File4.PNG
File5.PNG
File6.PNG
File7.PNG
File8.PNG
File9.PNG
Filetest463.docx
```

Comment: why are you opening and closing file for every run? You should open word doc outside loop, loop through images, insert them and outside the loop close the word document

Comment: I have tried it. there is an exception:
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\reports\test463\images (Access is denied)

Comment: How does it relates to Selenium? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is riddled with wrong if statements and faulty logic.

1. `list[k].isFile()` in the below code is enough. We are checking whether the list of files in the source folder is is a FILE or an FOLDER. If FILE, we can go ahead and add it. Then why the next if `if(srcfile.isFile()){` ? This will always evaluate to false because srcfile is your source folder `File srcfile=new File("C:\\reports\\test" + fileName() + "\\images");`

   ```
   for(int k=0;k<list.length;k++){
       if (list[k].isFile()){
           System.out.println("File"+list[k].getName());
           if(srcfile.isFile()){
   ```
2. We don't have to create docx using file input stream `XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(fis);` as in below code. The following is enough `XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();`. So all the `FileInputStream` and related logic can be removed.

   ```
   System.out.println("File"+list[k].getName());
       if(srcfile.isFile()){
           FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(srcfile);
           XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(fis);
   ```
3. The image name is not known to us as we are given the source folder only. The why is the source image name given as `"C:\\reports\\test"+ fileName() + "\\images\\"+imageName() + ".png"`.  We are iterating the source folder files and `list[k]` holds the image. So `list[k].getPath()` should get the image path.

   ```
      r.addPicture (fis, XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG,
   ```

   "C:\reports\test"+ fileName() + "\images\"+imageName() + ".png", 
   Units.toEMU(200), Units.toEMU(200));
4. If the file in the source folder is a directory, we are repeating the same logic for if the file is a file object. Both the `if` and `else if` does the same thing. What you need here is a recursive logic.

   ```
    else if (list[k].isDirectory()){
       System.out.println("Directory"+list[k].getName());
       if(srcfile.isFile()){
           FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(srcfile);
           XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(fis);
   ```
5. The document creation can be moved outside the loop.
6. `destfile.getParentFile().mkdir();` should be changed to `destfile.getParentFile().mkdirs();` if all the paremt folder structure has to be created.

Working code after correcting the issues.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {

    // Create the destination file and folder structure
    File destfile = new File("C:\\Evidences\\test\\imgdocx.docx");
    destfile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    destfile.createNewFile();

    // Create the docx object
    XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();

    // Get the source folder and list of files (includes images and
    // sub-folders)
    File srcfile = new File("C:\\reports\\test\\images");
    File[] list = srcfile.listFiles();
    System.out.println("Source folder item list " + list.length);

    // Iterate through the files in the source folder
    for (int k = 0; k < list.length; k++) {
        if (list[k].isFile()) {
            System.out.println("File - " + list[k].getName());

            // Create paragraph
            XWPFParagraph p = doc.createParagraph();
            XWPFRun r = p.createRun();

            // Create fis for image
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(list[k].getPath());
            // add image using the fis
            r.addPicture(fis, XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG,
                    list[k].getPath(),
                    Units.toEMU(200), Units.toEMU(200));
            fis.close();

        } else if (list[k].isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println("Directory - " + list[k].getName());
            // If directory do nothing
            // A recursive logic can be implemented to handle the files
            // inside folders in source folder
        }
    }

    // write docx to destination file
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destfile);
    doc.write(fos);
    fos.close();
    doc.close();
}
```

Comment: How to ensure the for loop fetches the images from srcfile in sequence? currently it is copying as below: File0.PNG File1.PNG File10.PNG File2.PNG File3.PNG File4.PNG File5.PNG File6.PNG File7.PNG File8.PNG File9.PNG But i need them to be copied in sequence. can you pls help me. thanks in advance!